# Are "Zero" and "Interface Zero" the same RPG?

Tags: interface-zero, indie-rpg

I've seen mentions of both in discussions - are they one RPG, or two?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No.

[ZERO](http://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?mainid=340) was a strange experimental game from Archangel Entertainment that came out in 1997. [Interface Zero](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product_info.php?products_id=83289&affiliate_id=82894) is a contemporary cyberpunk RPG with both Savage Worlds and Modern20 implementations. Two separate games.

Comment: I just picked up a copy of the Zero RPG from Archangel Entertainment. It looks like a great sci-fi setting for an RPG if players need a break from standard fantasy and sci-fi RPG themes.